# How to take lazy bytestring from zip archive without heap overflow

Tags: haskell, zip, memory-leaks

I want to take first five bytes from the fist file in zip archive. I use zip-archive package  for decompression:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment (getArgs)

import Codec.Archive.Zip

main = do
    f:_ <- getArgs
    print . L.take 5 . fromEntry . head . zEntries . toArchive =<< L.readFile f
```

This code works for small archives but I got heap overflow with big ones. For example:

```
./zip-arch test.zip +RTS -p -hy -M100M
```

for this [archive](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52911301/test.zip) gives this [heap profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfW40.png)

Comment: That heap profile shows a heap usage of 130k, that's no indication of a problem. I'll take a look myself.

Comment: @DanielFischer strange, but I've got this error message:
Heap exhausted;
Current maximum heap size is 104857600 bytes (100 MB);
use `+RTS -M<size>' to increase it.

Comment: @tymmym: `fromEntry` uses CRC32 checksum from the package "digest". it does crc32 by invoking crc32 in zlib.h, this may consume some memory? I'm not sure.

Comment: The difficulty is explained here https://groups.google.com/group/haskell-cafe/browse_thread/thread/c469234a1a517882/7674c6fb19460cd5?hl=en#7674c6fb19460cd5 Maybe you could fork it on github and make the recommended repairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read the [explanation](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-August/081772.html) of the zip-archive author and decided to make recommended repairs. I've finished with a new library - [zip-conduit](https://github.com/tymmym/zip-conduit). Its main feature is constant memory usage without lazy IO. To take first five bytes from the fist file in the zip archive you can write:

```
import           System.Environment
import           Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB

import           Codec.Archive.Zip

main = do
    f:_ <- getArgs
    res <- withArchive f $ do
               name:_ <- fileNames
               source <- getSource name
               runResourceT $ source $$ CB.take 5
    print res
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling out to [unzip](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html). It's not super haskelly but it does the job. Perhaps all the haters out there should spend more time fixing or replacing broken libraries like [zip-archive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zip-archive) and less time on stackoverflow.

Standard disclaimer: no error checking present. this may leak handles. lazy i/o is lazy.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO (hSetBinaryMode)
import System.Process (StdStream(...), createProcess, proc, close_fds, std_out)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

unzipLBS :: FilePath -> IO L.ByteString
unzipLBS file = do
  let args = proc "unzip" ["-p", file]
      args' = args { std_out = CreatePipe, close_fds = True }

  (_, Just hOut, _, _) <- createProcess args'
  hSetBinaryMode hOut True
  L.hGetContents hOut

main :: IO ()
main = do
  f:_ <- getArgs
  print . L.take 5 =<< unzipLBS f
```

Seems to work:

```
$ runghc -Wall unzip.hs  ~/Downloads/test.zip
Chunk ",+\227F\149" Empty
```